# Is there a way to animate the gradients of a font?

Tags: javascript, css, webfonts, svg-animate, opentype-svg-font

Let’s say I would like to use this font:

```css
@font-face {
  src: url("https://cdn.glitch.global/f206356a-29f3-4941-a91f-d78ba238df98/Abelone-FREE.otf?v=1650648293770") format("opentype");
  font-family: "Abelone";
}

* {
  font-family: "Abelone";
  font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
Hello, world.
```

Is there a way to animate the included gradients with CSS or JavaScript? If not, are there alternative ways to do something similar using just SVG or clipping masks, for example?

**Important:** Chrome doesn’t show the gradients. Please use Firefox to view them.

#### Edit: Opentype Svg font display/rendering

[image: Opentype Svg (colored) Font Support]

1. Colored Opentype Svg fonts supported (firefox, edge, ios safari)
2. Opentype Svg font features not supported (e.g chrome)

**About used font: [ColorFontWeek – Abelone](https://blog.adobe.com/en/publish/2017/11/02/color-font-week-abelone)**

Comment: What gradients are you talking about?

Comment: Carefull! Some old and mobile browser don't support this font.

Comment: Please update your question to explain what you mean with "the included gradients" given that there are no colours, let alone colour gradients, in the runnable snippet you've put in your post.

Comment: Unfortunately, the gradients are not visible with many browsers. Please check it with Firefox, for example.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with an CSS filter.

HTML Code:

```
<div class=animated>Does it work?</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.animated {
filter: hue-rotate(50deg);
}
```

This should change the colors.